# problem with video streaming in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-video-player

i m developing a simple application which will play video from a vlc streaming server through rtsp streaming...but while i m running the application it shows me a error like this
"Mediaplayer Error(1,-21474648),Videoview Error:1,-21474648","ARTSPConnectio Status:RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported transport"and MyHandler SETUP(1) completed with result 0" in the logCat and also displaying "this video can not be played" in the emulator..

I did a lot of Google on it..but didn't find a solution,below is my code

```
   public class VideoDemo extends Activity 
          {
   private VideoView video;
   private MediaController ctlr;

            @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
   ctlr=new MediaController(this);
   video.setMediaController(ctlr);
   video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.1.2:5544/sample"));

   video.requestFocus();
   video.start();

            }
       }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no problem with your code. please try these URI:

```
rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov

http://www.wowza.com/_h264/BigBuckBunny_175k.mov
```

If you are using your own video server, please make sure the video streaming works.